# Using Geb Browser object from Grails test phase events

Tags: grails, geb

I have a Grails event handler like this in `scripts/_Events.groovy`

```
eventTestPhaseStart = {
  geb.Browser.drive { go "http://localhost:8080/...." }
}
```

And `grails test-app -functional` logs an error

```
"The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; ... "
```

My `GebConfig.groovy` is set up to use PhantomJS or Chrome, and my tests themselves pass.  So I am guessing that at this point in the process, the Geb config hasn't been read yet.

Is there a way that I could use the Geb Browser object from the test phase start/end events?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to run some setup activities in the browser (e.g., clear localStorage) before all the tests run

Comment: Why not do it in a setup/cleanup method in a base spec?